# Question Regarding Notation : $\phi(n)\over{n}$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, notation

Following is what I have given equation.

$${\phi(n)\over{n}}= \sum_{d\mid n}{\mu(d)\over d}$$

The context is Combinatorics I think, but still vague which function does $\phi$ and $\mu$ refer to.

Any hint?

Comment: You mean $\phi(n)$, not $\emptyset(n)$: Euler's totient function. And $\mu$ is the Mobius function.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Is there any particular name for this equation?

Comment: @ZacharyYoon: it is a consequence of [Möbius inversion formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_inversion_formula)